# React Navigation | Como usar Navigation dentro de um componente React?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-router

Tenho um app com uma tela principal onde tudo deve acontecer. Estou usando a lib react-calendars para renderizar o calendário e em baixo há o conteúdo da aplicação, que seria dividido em 3 tabs, uma para adicionar anotações, ver anotações e outra para configurações pessoais.

O problema é que estou tentando utilizar o navigationContainer dentro deste container e não é renderizado nada com o Stack Navigation.

Dei uma procurada mas parece que o React Navigation só renderiza screens como componentes? Sendo assim eu não poderia deixar o calendário estático pra todas as telas e mudar apenas os componentes em baixo?

Esse é meu JSX:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Calendar
    style={styles.Calendar}
    onDayPress={(day) => {handleDatesClicked(day)}}
    markedDates={datesClicked}
    />
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Events" 
    screenOptions={{headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#FFD426',}, }}>

    <Stack.Screen name="Events" component={Events} />
    <Stack.Screen name="AddEvents"  component={AddEvents} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Person" component={Person} />

  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>

<Footer />

</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tens de fazer uma divisão da tua aplicação. A navegação é uma parte distinta da renderização e nem devem estar nos mesmos ficheiros.

Se o objetivo é ter uma navegação em tabs tens documentação específica para isso no site do [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/)